# Calling Action Of Controller Through onchange of Select But Not Through Ajax (Zend Framework)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-controller

i have a html select with options in my views .`onchange`i want to invoke action of my controller.
**Important:** i am not going to do this through Ajax because `onchange` my whole module is changing so i want to refresh a page each time onchange.

```
                   <select id="p_s">
                   <?php  foreach($this->active_services as $row){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['ph_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['ph_name'];?></option>
                      <?php }?>
                    </select>
```

the action i am calling also included the below code so i am not going to do it through ajax.

```
            if(!$this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
             //The request was not  made with JS XmlHttpRequest
              $user = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
              $user_id =$user->user_id;  
              $object   = new Services();
              $active_services     = $object->Get_Current_User_Active_Services($user_id);
              $this->view->assign('active_services',$active_services );
            }
```

the action i am calling is invoking through both ajax and normal this time i am calling it normal.
Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @vencislaf sir my question is that i want to call my controller action  through onchange of my select but not through ajax in a normal way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="p_s">
    <?php foreach($this->active_services as $row) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->url(array(
                "module" => "yourModule",
                "controller" => "yourController",
                "action" => "yourAction",
                "p_s" => $row['ph_id']
            ),
            $yourRouteName=null,
            $reset=true); 
            ?>
         ">
            <?php echo $row['ph_name'];?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Then

```
$("#p_s").change(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: sir i want to send $row['ph_id'] as a parameter to my action ??does the code you provided doing so ??

Comment: yourRouteName ??? example please.sir plz dont mind my awkward questions i am new to ZF

Comment: `$yourRouteName` is optional if you want to use a custom route that you have defined. If you don't, set it to `null`. `$row['ph_id']` will be set as `p_s` parameter (see `"p_s" => $row['ph_id']`).